# How to pick image from gallery on fragment?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to make a fragment that has function that when i click on button, gallery will open, then i choose an image and that image would be put into my imageview.

This is the code i wrote:

```
class PostFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_post) {

    companion object{
        val IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View{
        val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false)

        var ButtonChooseImage: Button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image)
        var postImage: ImageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.postImage)
        ButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener{
            openFileChooser()
        }
        return rootView
    }

    private fun openFileChooser() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val rootView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post,null)
        var postImage: ImageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.postImage)

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            postImage.setImageURI(data?.data)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except image does not show up in imageview. (after i press button gallery pops up, i choose an image but it doesnt show up in imageview.)

Where am i mistaken? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inflating the view a second time. What you are doing is creating a new layout, invisible to you, and you post your image there.

There are many solutions to this. You could try for example,

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val postImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.postImage) // <--------

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        postImage.setImageURI(data?.data)
    else super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Or,

```
lateinit var postImage: ImageView // <--------

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_post, container, false)

    postImage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.postImage) // <--------

    rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_choose_image)
        .setOnClickListener{ openFileChooser() }
    return rootView
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        postImage.setImageURI(data?.data)
    else super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

}
```

Or other ways, like [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Solved it. Appreciate a lot!